# Content underflowing to previous column in CSS columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[This example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PMGpGW) I made on code pen explains it perfectly.

I used the following code to show it happening. Just hover the second card in the top row.

```
.custom-hover:hover {
   transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Basically whenever the top element from any row but the first overflows, it shows up in the bottom of the previous column.

How can I fix this, if it's even possible?

Comment: make the origin of transform at the top

Comment: That's not really the point, the transform was just for illustration purposes. For example, if you look closely, the top of the shadows also appear at the bottom of the previous column

Comment: add some margin to fix the shadow ...

Comment: Doesn't work, see the codepen

Comment: margin to the element, not the container

Comment: Check it again. It still behaves in a weird way. And that'd be a hack and not really a fix imo

Answer (score 0):

I did some small reading and found that there seems to be a Chrome bug. I then tried different things and the changes below works for Firefox, Chrome and even on Opera.

```
.custom-hover:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border : 1px solid #000000;
  width : 90%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

You can remove the border if you don't want it.

Comment: z-index is the code I added as above to get the expected hover effect. I tested with 1000, 100, 10 and 1. The real question is : Did you test before asking if I'm sure ?

Comment: I just realized that you have added the z-index to your code and the hover effect now looks fine. Can you please confirm to us that your problem is now solved?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PMGpGW here's the actual code, it's not working. The url above is using columns for each card which breaks functionality. I accidentally updated the original URL

Comment: I have nothing to add. Without the z-index, hovering was( using your own words ) 'underflowing'. What I see now is that the z-index solves that problem. Can you please clarify what you mean by it is not working? Anyway this question is now behind me.

Comment: I just tested it on firefox and it's fixed there. It's not really fixed on Chrome though and that might be why it's fixed for you and not for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row mt-5">

       <div class="col-4 mb-4">
          <div class="custom-hover card shadow test">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-4 mb-4">
          <div class="custom-hover card shadow test">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-4 mb-4">
          <div class="custom-hover card shadow test">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-4 mb-4">
          <div class="custom-hover card shadow test">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-4 mb-4">
          <div class="custom-hover card shadow test">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-4 mb-4">
          <div class="custom-hover card shadow test">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
                <p>Hello there</p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose of using card-columns. If they have different heights they won't "stack" against each other. You can check the code pen with the new heights